# If either of two cells contain a specific value, return another value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to figure out how to perform this calculation. If A1 or B1 contain "text value 1" return C1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an IF and OR, or two IF statements.

```
=IF( OR(A1="text value1";B1="text value1") ;C1;"")
```

or

```
=IF(A1="text value 1";C1;IF(B1="text value 1";C1;""))
```

The difference here is that the 1st one will result `empty` if **both** have text value 1, where the 2nd will always return C1 if either or both of them have this text.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the formula `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:B1,"*text value 1*")>0,C1)`.

------- Update ---------

To replace "False" with 0, you could use the formula `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:B1,"*Mast*")>0,C1,0)`.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that works. Is there any way to add an elseif value of 0 instead of FALSE?

Comment: @Jonathon I have updated my previous reply. Please have a check ~